# How to connect JTAG to microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, jtag

I am using the STM32G030C8 and want to use a 6 pin JTAG Needle to program the microcontroller.

In the datasheet for the microcontroller, on page 14 it says:

[image: Boot modes]

So I need to connect whatever is programming the microcontroller to pins PB6 and PB7 for example as well as PA14 as this is the BOOT pin. Is this correct?

However it says in the datasheet, pins PB6 and PB7 are for USART- am I correct in saying you cannot use JTAG for this?

How can I find out which pins to connect the JTAG connector to?

[image: JTAG pinout]

The JTAG pinout is shown above. Am I correct in saying I would connect pins 1 and 5 to my VDD and GND nets respectively, and pins 2 and 4 to the microcontroller for programming?

Answer (score 1):

The STM32G030C8 doesn't have jtag. It has ARM Serial Wire Debig (SWD) where you also showed the connector for.

These you hook up to the equivalent named pins on the chip, PA13 and PA14.
SWO is trace output and optional.
Reset is also optional, if PA13/14 remain in their default configuration.

PB6 and 7 are for use with the built-in bootloader over UART, if BOOT0 is high on power-up.

See chapter 2.5 Boot configuration in the reference manual.